# Is it fine that I deleted stuff in programdata?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I deleted folders of apps that I don't have anymore and take up lots of gigabytes.

Is that ok?

Will nothing happen?

I deleted avast, f-secure, manticore games, badlion client.

I can delete all of those programdata folders without
anything happening right?

I don't have any of them.

I also have a restore
point anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProgramData is as the name says. It is for data for Programs. If a program (you mentioned Avast) is not blocking the attempt to delete, then you can delete the data.

There is no harm in doing this. Programs are kept in Program Files which is secured and which you manage with Programs and Features.

So you are fine deleting old data there.

Sometimes I will put this stuff on a temporary USB key, but that is just me and it is personal preference whether you would do the same thing.

Good Luck.